# "Quit and Open safari extension preferences" button not working. (While converting Chrome extension to Safari Web Extension)

Tags: ios, swift, converters, safari-extension

I have an issue, while running Safari Web Extension, gives pop up "You can turn on App's extension in Safari Extensions Preferences", but when I click on the button, it does not disappear nor did anything.

I have checked my ".appex" file included on all places where it should be. and permissions I have given are:

"permissions": [
"scripting",
"bookmarks"
],

I have stuck from days and searched a lot but didn't get anything!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code, we have no idea if you edited any of the files. If you did not edit any of the files, the associatd code should be in `Script.js` and associated function `openPreferences`. That sends a message to `ViewController.swift`. Make sure you did not change anything in `Main.html`, specifically the `<button class="open-preferences">` element.

Comment: No, I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this by changing the default bundle identifier, I have changed bundle identifier after conversion, in code there was older bundle identifier in ViewController file.

```
let extensionBundleIdentifier = "com.yourCompany.App.Extension"
```

This variable should have your actual bundle ID.